# mysql getting all unanswered questions for a single user

Tags: mysql

ive uploaded the 3 different tables i use and is relevant to this question here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/796b2f/1

here's what im trying to do:

I want to know the unanswered questions by this user (id #39). He's listed in the **logins** table. The **surveyquestions** table holds all the questions. The **completedsurveyquestions** table holds all the answers. Those two tables join on **s.id** and **c.surveyquestionid**. Which user has answered which question is found under **c.userid** and joins on **l.id**.

Here's the sql query i use:

```
SELECT * FROM surveyquestions s
LEFT JOIN completedsurveyquestions c 
ON s.id = c.surveyquestionid
LEFT JOIN logins l
ON INSTR(l.opensurveys, s.surveytype) > 0 #check if theres any open surveys for the user
WHERE l.id = 39
AND c.surveyquestionid IS NULL #makes sure the question isnt actually completed
```

Sadly this query only works if the question has never been answered. How do i make the query so it can handle multiple users? In my case, it should show all the questions since user 39 hasnt completed any questions.

Thanks for any and all help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do for single or multiple users:

```
SELECT * FROM surveyquestions s
    cross join logins l
    left join completedsurveyquestions c
    on (s.id = c.surveyquestionid and l.id=c.userid)
    where c.userid is null
    and INSTR(l.opensurveys, s.surveytype) > 0
    and l.id in (userid1, userid2, userid3, . . .);
```

This is **very** inefficient due to the schema/architecture choices.  You essentially have to do a cartesian product between logins and questions and then left outer join to see which questions have been completed.  You can see which questions a user hasn't completed by seeing if there is no corresponding userid in the completedsurveyquestions table for the cartesian product.  If this is a query you will be doing a lot, you should **definitely** revisit your schema and application architecture.

Comment: your answer removes the "ON INSTR(l.opensurveys, s.surveytype) > 0" and since you dont fetch any data from the logins table, how do i add that to the 2nd query?

Comment: okay, im not really educated on how to do the most efficient ways of db structure so i do what i can. but you removed the first answer about fetching a single user. could you add that back so i can see if i need the answer for a single person?

Comment: It still works for single user, just use one user ID.

Comment: @Munik:  you can also see the historyof your sqlfiddle liiii|:)  I did many, many versions trying to see what I could do to get this as simple as possible.

Comment: if i use id 39 in your answer it works, if i change its id of the user to 23 or whatever, it doesnt work. im doing this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/12478a/2 and i dont know how to check history of sqlfiddles. im sorry if im not that smart with this, im just trying to learn

Comment: @Munik:  That’s a very silly question.  User 23 has 0 open surveys so of course the query will return 0 results.  I thought that was what you wanted to have happen?

Comment: im sorry, apperently you know more about my code than i do. had no idea that it wasnt open. thanks for all the help to a newbie

Answer (score 0):

SELECT sdata.*
,l.id 
FROM  ( select s.surveytype, s.id sid, c.id  cid, c.userid from surveyquestions s
    LEFT JOIN completedsurveyquestions c 
    ON s.id = c.surveyquestionid) sdata
     join  logins l
     on    (INSTR(l.opensurveys, sdata.surveytype) > 0
     or INSTR(l.opensurveys, sdata.surveytype) = 0 )
     where l.id = 39

plz check this, I just remove some columns from select

Comment: This is very discouraging that u even did'nt check mine solution which has solved your problem.